# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

Hola que tal? estoy empezando a aprender mvc 5 con entity framework y tengo este problema al momento de querer mostrar en un `foreach` un grupo de datos, estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema de un aeropuerto muy básico como practica

```
public class City
{

    private string _id;
    private string _name;

    public City()
    {
        _id = "";
        _name = "";
    }

    public City(string id)
    {
        _id = id;
        //query
        string query = "select name from cities where id=@ID";
        //command
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
        //execute
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        // DataTable tabLe = SqlServerConnection.ExecuteQuery(command);



    }

    public City(string idCity, int id)
    {
        _id = idCity;
        using (airport2018Entities2 db = new airport2018Entities2())
        {


        }


    }
    public City(string id, string name)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    public string Id { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }

    public IQueryable<Flight> GetDeparturesL()
    {
        List<Flight> departures = new List<Flight>();

        airport2018Entities2 db = new airport2018Entities2();


        var query = (from f in db.flights
                     join a in db.airlines on f.airlineId equals a.id
                     join dc in db.cities on f.departureCityId equals dc.id
                     join ac in db.cities on f.arrivalCityId equals ac.id
                     where f.departureCityId == _id
                     select new Flight()
                     {
                         Id = f.id,
                         Airline = new Airline(a.id, a.name),
                         Date = f.date,
                         DepartureTime = f.departureTime,
                         ArrivalTime = f.arrivalTime,
                         Arrival = new City(f.arrivalCityId, ac.name),
                         Departure = new City(f.departureCityId, dc.name),
                         Status = f.status
                     });




        return query;



    }
    public City GetCities()
    {
        airport2018Entities2 db = new airport2018Entities2();

        var query = db.cities.First();

        City city = new City(query.id,query.name);

        return city;
    }

    public IQueryable<Flight> GetArrivalsL()
    {
        List<Flight> arrivals = new List<Flight>();
        airport2018Entities2 db = new airport2018Entities2();

            var query = (from f in db.flights
                         join a in db.airlines on f.airlineId equals a.id
                         join dc in db.cities on f.departureCityId equals dc.id
                         join ac in db.cities on f.arrivalCityId equals ac.id
                         where f.arrivalCityId == _id
                         select new Flight()
                         {
                             Id = f.id,
                             Airline = new Airline(a.id, a.name),
                             Date = f.date,
                             DepartureTime = f.departureTime,
                             ArrivalTime = f.arrivalTime,
                             Arrival = new City(f.arrivalCityId, ac.name),
                             Departure = new City(f.departureCityId, dc.name),
                             Status = f.status
                         });

            return query;




    }
}
```

Este es el modelo donde cree mis métodos para mostrar la información de salidas y llegadas de aviones, como pueden ver.

Cree tambien una clase que tiene dos listas como propiedades para poder guardar el grupo de llegadas y salidas

```
public class ViewModel
{

    public IQueryable<airport.Models.Flight> FlightsA { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<airport.Models.Flight> FlightsD { get; set; }
}
```

Y después los métodos los pongo en marcha en este controlador para así ir al `view` con los datos

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {

        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

        airport.Models.City city = new airport.Models.City(id);
        model.FlightsA = city.GetArrivalsL();
        model.FlightsD = city.GetDeparturesL();
        return View(model);



    }
```

Aquí esta el razor de mi `view`

```html
@Model ViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Arrivals</h2>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Airline</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var f in Model.FlightsA)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@f.Id</td>
                <td>@f.Date</td>
                <td>@f.DepartureTime</td>
                <td>@f.Arrival.Name</td>
                <td>@f.Airline.Name</td>
                <td>@f.Status</td>
            </tr>
        }


    </tbody>

</table>
<h2>Departures</h2>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>Airline</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var f in Model.FlightsD)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@f.Id</td>
                <td>@f.Date</td>
                <td>@f.DepartureTime</td>
                <td>@f.Arrival.Name</td>
                <td>@f.Airline.Name</td>
                <td>@f.Status</td>
            </tr>
        }


    </tbody>

</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase de flight

```
 public class Flight
{
    private int _id;
    private Airline _airline;
    private DateTime _date;
    private TimeSpan _departureTime;
    private TimeSpan _arrivalTime;
    private City _arrival;
    private City _departure;
    private int _status;


    public int Id { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
    public Airline Airline { get { return _airline; } set { _airline = value; } }
    public DateTime Date { get { return _date; } set { _date = value; } }
    public TimeSpan DepartureTime { get { return _departureTime; } set { _departureTime = value; } }
    public TimeSpan ArrivalTime { get { return _arrivalTime; } set { _arrivalTime = value; } }
    public int Status { get { return _status; } set { _status = value; } }
    public City Arrival { get { return _arrival; } set { _arrival = value; } }
    public City Departure { get { return _departure; } set { _departure = value; } }
    public City Arrival1 { get { return _arrival; } set { _arrival = value; } }
    public City Departure1 { get { return _departure; } set { _departure = value; } }
    public Airline Airline1 { get { return _airline; } set { _airline = value; } }


}
```

Comment: El problema te lo da, casi seguro, al intentar recorrer un elemento de tipo IQueryable. No respondo a tu pregunta con respuesta elaborada porque nunca he trabajado  con IQueryable a ese nivel; lo que al final necesita ese foreach en tu cshtml view es un elemento que coleccione elementos (yo siempre he trabajado con List<T>). Tendrías que transformar el IQueryable<FligthsA> a List<FlightsA>. Pero ya te digo, no estoy nada seguro de que funcione lo que digo.

Comment: Igual poniendo esto te sirve: "foreach (var f in Model.FlightsA.ToList())"

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, en cualquiera de los dos metodos al cambiar a List me muestra ese mismo error en el return, por eso cambie a IQueryable

Comment: Siento no poder ser de más ayuda. Me quedo pendiente de esta pregunta, que me interesa conocer la solución de alguien que aporte más y mejor que yo.

Comment: Si estas usando EF no necesitas hacer llamadas a BBDD entre objetos relacionados. Basta con configurar el context para que traiga toda la información

https://entityframework.net/es/knowledge-base/30608266/entity-framework-relaciones-entre-diferentes-dbcontext-y-diferentes-esquemas

Comment: Si te refieres al constructor de un solo parametro ya es codigo obsoleto, lo que pasa es que estoy migrando un pequeño trabajo hecho a conexion sqlcommand a entity framework, olvide cambiar ese constructor

Comment: Entonces no necesitas hacer el new:
 select new Flight()
                         {
                             Airline = new Airline(a.id, a.name),
                             Arrival = new City(f.arrivalCityId, ac.name)
                         });

 select new Flight()
                         {
                             Airline.Id = a.id,
                             Airline.Name = a.name
                             Arrival.Id = f.arrivalCityId,
                             Departure.Id = f.departureCityId
                         });

Comment: @JosueLeonardoGalindoMiranda: Hola, podrías indicar el código de la Clase `Flight`?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta listo la añadi

Comment: @J4ime si entiendo, lo que pasa es que no me famirializo totalmente con entity framework ya que aprendi a programar en .net como en la vieja escuela, todo a mano usando solamente sqlcommand, si tienes algun sitio mas donde pueda ver mas a detalle lo que me dices estaria super bien

Comment: @JosueLeonardoGalindoMiranda https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/

mírate sobretodo la creación de modelos que los tienes mal, no hace falta ya los get y set con parametros...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no puedes recorrer directamente un IQueryable y creo que tampoco se pueden usar constructores dentro de selects de Linq, cambia tus métodos GetDeparturesL y GetArrivalsL por:

```
public List<Flight> GetDeparturesL()
{
    airport2018Entities2 db = new airport2018Entities2();

    List<Flight> flights = (from f in db.flights
         join a in db.airlines on f.airlineId equals a.id
         join dc in db.cities on f.departureCityId equals dc.id
         join ac in db.cities on f.arrivalCityId equals ac.id
         where f.departureCityId == _id
         select new Flight()
         {
             Id = f.id,
             Airline = new Airline(){ Id = a.id, Name = a.name },
             Date = f.date,
             DepartureTime = f.departureTime,
             ArrivalTime = f.arrivalTime,
             Arrival = new City(){ Id = f.arrivalCityId, Name = ac.name },
             Departure = new City(){ Id = f.departureCityId, Name = dc.name },
             Status = f.status
         }).ToList();

    return flights;
}


public List<Flight> GetArrivalsL()
{
    airport2018Entities2 db = new airport2018Entities2();

    List<Flight> flights = (from f in db.flights
         join a in db.airlines on f.airlineId equals a.id
         join dc in db.cities on f.departureCityId equals dc.id
         join ac in db.cities on f.arrivalCityId equals ac.id
         where f.arrivalCityId == _id
         select new Flight()
         {
             Id = f.id,
             Airline = new Airline(){ Id = a.id, Name = a.name },
             Date = f.date,
             DepartureTime = f.departureTime,
             ArrivalTime = f.arrivalTime,
             Arrival = new City(){ Id = f.arrivalCityId, Name = ac.name },
             Departure = new City(){ Id = f.departureCityId, Name = dc.name }
             Status = f.status
         }).ToList();

     return flights;
}
```

La clase ViewModel por:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<airport.Models.Flight> FlightsA { get; set; }
    public List<airport.Models.Flight> FlightsD { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: entonces solo cambiaste los iqueryable por list, y los constructores por object initializer, linq si te permite usar objects initializers en los select?

Comment: y muchas gracias, si funciono, apenas hasta ahorita te doy el credito aqui por cuestiones de tiempo, pero me has resuelto el conflicto que tenia